# Function inheritance - call method in super class on child.apply()

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following:

```
abstract class ParentFunction extends Function[String, String] {
  def useful: Any = // do something useful, such as notifying a listener
}

class ChildFunction extends ParentFunction {
  override def apply(arg: String): String = "Did something special, and something generally useful!"
}
```

Is there any way, *apart from explicitly invoking 'useful'*, that I can make sure that 'useful' is *implicitly* called whenever ChildFunction (or any other descendant of ParentFunction is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply not have the children provide `apply` but some other method:

```
abstract class ParentFunction extends Function[String, String] {
  def useful: Any = println("Doing useful work")
  def doWork(arg: String): String
  override final def apply(arg: String): String = {
    useful
    doWork(arg)
  }
}

class ChildFunction extends ParentFunction {
  override def doWork(arg: String): String = "Did something special"
}
```

Alternately, make the useful bit a different abstraction:

```
object UsefulTool {
  def withNotification(f: => String) {
    useful
    f
  }
  def useful = ???
}
```

Then you can wrap any work:

```
UsefulTool.withNotification {
  "Did something special"
}
```

And of course, pass in methods for ease of testing:

```
def doSpecial: String = "Did something special"

val result = UsefulTool.withNotification doSpecial _
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood your problem correctly. You could define that in the apply of `ParentFunction` and just let the children pass a `Function[String, String]`.

```
class ParentFunction(func: String => String) extends Function[String, String] {
  def useful: Any = println("useful")

  def apply(s: String) = {
    useful
    func(s)
  }
}

object ChildFunction extends ParentFunction(
  s => "Did something special, and something generally useful! " + s
)

println(ChildFunction("child"))
```

which prints:

```
useful
Did something special, and something generally useful! child
```

Comment: I don't think this is what op is looking for: "_apart from explicitly invoking 'useful'_", not sure if he meant also not in the apply method.

Comment: The sub-classes don't have to deal with `useful` now. I guessed that was the intention.